# What's the difference between running code in Observable.Select() and Observable.Subscribe()?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

When execute some Async function, we have to use `Observable.Select()`. For example,

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
timer
    .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(cancellationToken)))
    .Concat()
    .Subscribe();
```

Using async function in `Subscribe()` will have problems.

```
timer.Subscribe(async tick => await DoSomething(cancellationToken));
```

Can the subscription logic be run in `Select()` always? (use `.Select(...my logic...).Subscribe();` instead of `.Subscribe(...my logic...);`)

Why `Subscribe()`

Answer (score 2):

There's a big semantic difference in the two blocks of code.

Try this complete program:

```
void Main()
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    
    var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0)).Take(5);

    // A
    timer
        .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(cancellationToken)))
        .Concat()
        .Subscribe();

    // B
    //timer.Subscribe(async tick => await DoSomething(cancellationToken));
}

public async Task<Unit> DoSomething(CancellationToken ct)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200.0));
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End");
    return Unit.Default;
}
```

When I run that I get this output:

```
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
```

But when I comment out `A` and uncomment `B` I get this:

```
DoSomething Start
DoSomething Start
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
DoSomething End
DoSomething Start
DoSomething Start
DoSomething End
DoSomething End
DoSomething End
```

`.Subscribe` does not understand what a ``` async``/ ```await` delegate is. It starts running and returns to the caller allowing the next value to be produced from the observable.

Using the `Select`/`FromAsync`/`Concat` method you ensure that the `DoSomething` is run one at a time, without overlapping.

You'd also get the correct results if you changed `B` to `timer.Subscribe(tick => DoSomething(cancellationToken).Wait());`. But this starts to show that there is something wrong with running `async` in a subscribe.

If you want to run `async` blocks in your subscribe then you need to give the compiler an extension method that does know how to await properly. Try this:

```
public static class ObservableEx2
{
    public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task> onNext) =>
        source
            .Select(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => onNext(t)))
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe();           
}
```

Now the code runs as expected when I run `B`.

Comment: You could also mention that the first approach (the A in the answer) might result in a memory leak, in case the `DoSomething` consistently outlasts the duration of the `Observable.Interval`. The `Concat` is going to buffer a forever increasing number of `Observable.FromAsync` sequences.

Comment: I did make up this code to demonstrate the issue. You're right though in principle, but it's not a memory leak. It all gets properly cleaned up when the subscription ends.

Comment: The OP has not included the `.Take(5)` in their code, so I guess that their intention is to run the timer indefinitely. Or until a `DoSomething` fails, in which case the process will crash with an unhandled exception. So the possibility for a memory leak is real. If the timer ticks faster than the handler of each tick, the memory footprint of the process will grow over time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I agree that the memory footprint grows, but an exception should properly clean up the memory.

Comment: The naked `Subscribe`, that lacks the `onError` handler, will escalate any error to a process-crashing event. Which, yes, will cause the operating system to properly clean up the memory.